# Match start and end of word in Multiple line using Perl Regex

Tags: perl

I have a multiple-line text, need to match the text starting word and ending word of multiple lines in perl command

Multipleline text

```
Start here 
line 1
line 2
line 3
End
```

tired the below command to match the text, but it is only working single line, Need to match multiple line.

```
'(^Start.+End$)'
```

Comment: Use `DOTALL` or single line mode

Answer (score 1):

- Those quotes shouldn't be there.
- You want the `s` modifier to make `.` match any character including line feeds.
- You want the `m` modifier if you want `^` and `$` to match start and end of line (as opposed to start and end of string).
- A common mistake is to repeatedly match against only one line instead of matching once against the entire text.

For example,

```perl
my $text = <<'.';
...
Start here 
line 1
line 2
line 3
End
...
.

say $1 if $text =~ /(^Start.+End$)/sm;
```

Comment: I'd probably anchor that `End` to make sure I got the first one that was at the start of a line: `(^Start.+?^End$)`, but maybe it doesn't matter for the input.